# Avoid duplicating code when writing junit code for a method called by another one

Tags: junit

I'm new with Junit. I have 2 methods in tested class. Method A will call method B. In B, there are some condition cases that I need to cover when writing test case.

So, in this case, if I write test for B, then A, the tested code will be duplicated. Do you have any idea for this case?

The code looks like:

```
class Example{

public void A(){
  assert B();
  varA ++;

}

public boolean B(){

if (case1){
  var1B ++;
  if (case 1.1){
    var2B++;
    return false;
  }
}

var3B --;
return true;
}

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html) (or another mocking framework), to mock the method B when testing A, and make it return what you want:

```
Example example = spy(new Example());
when(example.B()).thenReturn(true);

// now call A() and test that it does what it should to when B() returns true.
```

Comment: Don't you feel that mocking the class under test has "test smell" and should be avoided? I am interested in your thoughts on this.

Comment: Mockito says that. I personally don't see why calling a method from another one in the same class is bad design. And this is the only way I see to test a method A without actually running the called method B. Of course you could put the object in a state that makes B return true or false, but it's sometime more complicated, and I prefer simpler tests than complex ones.

Comment: +1 for a simple design so long as user keeps above comments in mind

Comment: But I did not work. If in B calls another object, it will throw an exception (like null pointer). it does not run independently, right?

Comment: No, it won't, unless you use an old version of Mockito. WIth old versions, you must use `doReturn(true).when(example).B()`, IIRC. Read the documentation of your version of Mockito.

Comment: I still dont understand why. I imported mockito 1.9. In B(), it calls another object that is not set when new Example(). But I think if your way is correct, it does not matter, I'm trying to find why....

Comment: Mocking B means replacing the implementation of B by another implementation that returns what you tell the mock to return. So what B does in reality doesn't matter.

Comment: @JBNizet, do I need to add any annotation or something else? It seems the test code did not understand mockito, it does not simulate behaviours of method. the method is run like an instance. I'm using PowerMock combined with EasyMock. Thanks for help

Comment: Mockito and EasyMock are two different mocking framework. The above uses Mockito, not EasyMock. EasyMock also supports partial mocks, but they're a bit more cumbersome to use. Search for "Partial mocking" in [the documentation](http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html)

Comment: @JBNizet, it works with your solution. But I have to change a little bit. When creating constructor for A, I have to new C() that is called in B()(it is the reason to throw a NPE before). Like new A(xx,,yy, new c()). Then, expecting true or false of B(). +1

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to test `B` fully and then only test two cases of `B` when testing `A`: when `B` returns `true` and when it returns `false`. These two cases may be repeats but if you set up a utility method that will cause `B` to return the desired value there should be limit the the amount of repeated code.

You could have a method like:

```
void configureB(boolean case1, boolean case2){...}
```

Then use this method when testing `B` fully and use it to test the two conditions of `A`